# Reversing characters in a python string

Tags: python, reverse

I'm having trouble how to figure out how to just reverse a few words in a python string.

ex:

```
aString = "This is my string."
```

I know how to reverse the whole string, but I can't figure out how to reverse only a few words such as:

I need to reverse every word at an even index, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12

```
aString = "This si my gnirts"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate indices alongside the items after splitting with `str.split` and reverse those at **odd** (not even since counting starts from zero) indices. Use `str.join` to rebuild the string:

```
>>> s = "This is my string"
>>> ' '.join(x if i%2==0 else x[::-1] for i, x in enumerate(s.split()))
'This si my gnirts'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
newString = []
for index, i in enumerate(aString.split()):
   if i % 2 == 0:
      newString.append(i[::-1])
   else:
      newString.append(i)
newString = ''.join(newString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line...

```
out = ' '.join([x[::-1] if input.index(x)%2 == 1 else x for x in input.split(' ')])
```

EXAMPLE:

```
>>> input = 'here is an example test string'
>>> out = ' '.join([x[::-1] if input.index(x)%2 == 1 else x for x in input.split(' ')])
>>> out
'here si an elpmaxe tset string'
```

NOTE: I know you said that you were looking to reverse even indices in you original question, but it looked like you were actually looking for odd ones based on your example. Just switch the mod to %2==0 if I'm wrong about that.